# I need help proving that a certain subgroup is a direct product of specific subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, direct-product

Let G be a group, P be an abelian Sylow-p subgroup of G. Let $N=N_G(P)$ and assume that H is a complement of P in N which I believe means that $HP=N$ and $H\cap{P}=1$

Prove that $P = P_1 \times P_2$ where $P_1=C_P(H)$ and $P_2=[P,H]$

I understand that there's three things that I need to prove:

$P_1P_2=P$

$P_1\cap{P_2}=1$

elements of $P_1$ commute with elements of $P_2$

But I cannot seem to prove either of them.

I would appreciate any advice on how to approach this. Thank you.

Comment: I think  " a complement of $\;P\; $  in $\;G\;$" would mean that $\;HP=G\,,\,\,H\cap P=1\;$ , wouldn't it? But then I can't see what the role of $\;N\;$ is in this problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's meant to say that H is a complement of P in N which means that HP = N and the intersection of H and P is trivial (= 1)

Comment: I am surprised that this would be set as an exercise, because it is a textbook result. For example it is Theorem 2.3 of Chapter 5 of Gorenstein's "Finite Groups". The proof involves an averaging argument.

Comment: Thank you, I will look through the proof in "Finite Groups"